# Linq where clause using filter object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have a piece of Linq that queries an EntityFramework context in my web controller and returns the result, as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetRoutingRules()
{
     var query = (from rr in _context.RoutingRules
          join dest in _context.RoutingZones on rr.DestinationZoneId equals dest.ZoneId
          join origin in _context.RoutingZones on rr.OriginZoneId equals origin.ZoneId
          join hub in _context.RoutingHub on rr.HubId equals hub.HubId
          select new RoutingRulesDto(rr) { DestinationZoneName = dest.ZoneName, OriginZoneName = origin.ZoneName, HubName = hub.HubName });

     return Ok(query);
}
```

I want a new method that will take a "filter" object, where I can narrow down the results of the above.  My filter object looks like this:

```
public class RoutingSearchFilterDto
{
     public int BrandId { get; set; }
     public int? ServiceType { get; set; }
     public long? OriginZoneId { get; set; }
     public long? DestinationZoneId { get; set; }
     public int? RuleRanking { get; set; }
     public bool? IsRuleActive { get; set; }
}
```

The minimum info that needs to be set in this class is BrandId.  All other properties are options in the filter.

I need to write a new controller method that will utilise this, something like:

```
[HttpPost("filtered")]
public IActionResult GetFilteredRoutingRules([FromBody] RoutingSearchFilterDto filter)
{
    ...
}
```

How do I linq query on properties that could potentially be null?  Essentially, a dynamic query depending on the properties set in the filter object.

NOTE: I want this to affect the select statement that the EF runs, not just let EF get all the data, then filter the data set - the point of this is to make the db call more efficient.

Filter object might be sent where BrandId = 1, IsRuleActive = 1.  Equally, it could be BrandId = 1, ServiceType = 3 (and therefore IsRuleActive is null so shouldn't be in the linq where clause).

I've tried this:

```
var param = (Expression.Parameter(typeof(RoutingRules), "rr"));

Expression combinedExpr = null;
if (filter.BrandId != null)
{
    var exp = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "BrandId"), Expression.Constant(filter.BrandId));
    combinedExpr = exp;
}

if (filter.DestinationZoneId != null)
{
    var exp = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "DestinationZoneId"), Expression.Constant(filter.DestinationZoneId));
    combinedExpr = (combinedExpr == null ? exp : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpr, exp));
}

if (filter.OriginZoneId != null)
{
    var exp = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "OriginZoneId"), Expression.Constant(filter.OriginZoneId));
    combinedExpr = (combinedExpr == null ? exp : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpr, exp));
}

if (filter.EshopServiceType != null)
{
    var exp = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "EshopServiceType"), Expression.Constant(filter.EshopServiceType));
    combinedExpr = (combinedExpr == null ? exp : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpr, exp));
}

if (filter.IsRuleActive != null)
{
    var exp = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "IsRuleActive"), Expression.Constant(filter.IsRuleActive, typeof(bool?)));
    combinedExpr = (combinedExpr == null ? exp : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpr, exp));
}

if (filter.RuleRanking != null)
{
    var exp = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "RuleRanking"), Expression.Constant(filter.RuleRanking));
    combinedExpr = (combinedExpr == null ? exp : Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpr, exp));
}

if (combinedExpr == null)
    combinedExpr = Expression.Default(typeof(bool));

var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<RoutingRules, bool>>(combinedExpr, param).Compile();


var results = (from rr in _context.RoutingRules.Where(compiled)
                join dest in _context.RoutingZones on rr.DestinationZoneId equals dest.ZoneId
                join origin in _context.RoutingZones on rr.OriginZoneId equals origin.ZoneId
                join hub in _context.RoutingHub on rr.HubId equals hub.HubId
                where rr.BrandId == 21
                select new RoutingRulesDto(rr) { DestinationZoneName = dest.ZoneName, OriginZoneName = origin.ZoneName, HubName = hub.HubName });
```

But the Where clause isn't applied to the generated Sql, it seems to pull back all records, then apply the where in memory, which isn't what I need.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!!

Comment: You are not using the compiled expression anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have my final solution in black and white, here's what I had in the end:

```
[HttpPost("filtered")]
public IActionResult GetFilteredRoutingRules([FromBody] RoutingSearchFilterDto filter)
{
    // Query to be build on the routing rules table.
    IQueryable<RoutingRules> query = _context.RoutingRules;

    // Populate the linked foreign key entities.
    query.Include(x => x.Hub).Include(y => y.DestinationZone).Include(z => z.OriginZone);

    // Build dynamic where statements.
    if (filter.BrandId != null)
        query = query.Where(r => r.BrandId == filter.BrandId);

    if (filter.OriginZoneId != null)            
        query = query.Where(r => r.OriginZoneId == filter.OriginZoneId);

    if (filter.DestinationZoneId != null)
        query = query.Where(r => r.DestinationZoneId == filter.DestinationZoneId);

    if (filter.IsRuleActive != null)
        query = query.Where(r => r.IsRuleActive == filter.IsRuleActive);

    if (filter.RuleRanking != null)
        query = query.Where(r => r.RuleRanking == filter.RuleRanking);

    // If you want to add paging:
    query = query.Skip(filter.PageSize * filter.PageNumber).Take(filter.PageSize);

    // Perform select on the table and map the results.
    var result = query.Select(r => new RoutingRulesDto
    {
        RoutingRuleId = r.RoutingRuleId,
        BrandId = r.BrandId,
        LastMileCarrierCode = r.LastMileCarrierCode,
        CashOnDelivery = r.CashOnDelivery,
        CreationTime = r.CreationTime,
        CurrencyCode = r.CurrencyCode,
        CurrencyDescription = Enum.Parse(typeof(Enumerations.CurrencyCode), r.CurrencyCode),
        DestinationZoneId = r.DestinationZoneId,
        EddFromDay = r.EddFromDay,
        EddToDay = r.EddToDay,
        ServiceType = r.ServiceType,
        ServiceTypeName = Enum.Parse(typeof(Enumerations.ServiceType), r.EshopServiceType),
        IsPickUpAvailable = r.IsPickUpAvailable,
        LastUpdateTime = r.LastUpdateTime,
        LastUpdateUser = r.LastUpdateUser,
        OriginZoneId = r.OriginZoneId,
        RuleRanking = r.RuleRanking,
        SignOnDelivery = r.SignOnDelivery,
        TermsOfDelivery = r.TermsOfDelivery,
        TermsOfDeliveryName = Enum.Parse(typeof(Enumerations.TermsOfDelivery), r.TermsOfDelivery),
        ValueOfGoods = r.ValueOfGoods,
        WeightLowerLimit = r.WeightLowerLimit,
        WeightUpperLimit = r.WeightUpperLimit,
        FirstMileCarrierCode = r.FirstMileCarrierCode,
        HubId = r.HubId,
        IsInsuranceAvailable = r.IsInsuranceAvailable,
        IsRuleActive = r.IsRuleActive,
        HubName = r.Hub.HubName,
        DestinationZoneName = r.DestinationZone.ZoneName,
        OriginZoneName = r.OriginZone.ZoneName,
    });

    // The SQL produced includes the joins and where clauses as well as only 
    // selecting the column names that are required in the flattened return object.

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 4):

You *can* build an expression tree for this, but have you considered:

```
IQueryable<...> query = ...;

if (routingSearchFilter.ServiceType != null)
  query = query.Where(e => e.ServiceType == routingSearchFilter.ServiceType);

if (...) 
   query = query.Where(....);
```

The EF engine is smart enough to combine the Where clauses (with AND of course).

Edit:

It wasn't clear if you wanted to filter on the joined result or only on the first table. In that case it would continue like

```
var result = (from rr in query
          join dest in _context.RoutingZones on rr.DestinationZoneId equals dest.ZoneId
          join ...
          select new RoutingRulesDto(rr) .... ).ToSometing();
```

But I'm a little wary about that RoutingRulesDto(rr) constructor parameter.

Comment: Much simpler and easier to understand. You will be building the query step by step and it will not be executed until you start iterating the items. EF will create the correct where clause, it will not get all the data and filter it in memory.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify - this solution is great for adding a WHERE clause onto the sql dynamically BUT I've lost the ability to join using this format.  The sql generated should be like "SELECT t1.a,t1.b,t2.a FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Id = t1.FkId WHERE <dynamic clause>".  The solution above gives all except the join.

Comment: Ok guys - worked out how to populate the other fields (without the join) using this code:  
            IQueryable<RoutingRules> query = _context.RoutingRules.Include(x => x.Hub).Include(y => y.DestinationZone).Include(z => z.OriginZone);

Answer (score 2):

If you use the fluent API for LINQ, you can conditionally add `Where` clauses.

```
var query = _content.RoutingRules.Where(r => r.BrandId == filter.BrandId);
if (filter.OriginZoneId != null) {
    query = query.Where(r => r.OriginZoneId == filter.OriginZoneId);
}
if (filter.EshopServiceType != null) {
    query = query.Where(r => r.EshopServiceType == filter.EshopServiceType);
}
// etc...
var result = query.ToArray();
```